# Converting Text Received via JMS into XML

Tags: java, xml, jms

I am trying to convert a message which i receive through JMS, which is in this form "Harry PotterJ.K.Rowling1995"

This is stored as a String. For example String contents.

How do i convert this String contents into an XML file.

Thanks you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Smart ass answer:
 `String xmlString = "<myNewXmlString>" + myString + "</mynewXmlString>";`

If it's more complicated you may want to look at this:
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/

You probably also need some delimiter (a comma or colon separating the values) of the string to know What is a title, author and year.  You'd then need separate tags for each.  Another way to solve that is to use fixed width columns.  So authors are 50, titles are 50, and years are 4.  There are really three steps here: tokenizing the string, parsing the string into a data structure, and outputting the data structure to XML.

There are lots of automated tools that can convert a data structure like this:

```
class Book {
 String title;
 String author;
 Date year;
}
```

into XML as well.

See: http://jackson-users.ning.com/profiles/blogs/experimental-support-for

Comment: Hi Justin.. Thanks alot for the answer.. My text receive already has the sperate tags alread.. for example : <Book>Harry Potter</Book><Author>J.K.Rowling</Author>.. I just have to generate the XML. would this still work ?

Comment: Well technically the string is already XML.  So what do you want to do with it?  If you don't have to validate that it is actually XML you can just save it to a file, database, or other output stream.  If you do have to validate it then yes you'd need SAX or XERXES to parse the XML and make sure it is actually XML.